# Which are the common causes for non scalability of shared memory programs?

Tags: parallel-processing, scalability, shared-memory

Whenever someone paralelizes an application the expected outcome is a decent speedup, but is not always the case.

It is very usual that a program that runs in `x` seconds, parallelized to use 8 cores will not achieve `x/8` seconds (optimal speedup). In some extreme cases, it even takes more time than the original sequential program.

**Why?** and most importantly, how do I improve scalability?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few common causes of non scalability:

1. **Too much synchronization**: Some problems (and sometimes too much conservative programmers) require lots of synchronization between parallel tasks, this eliminates most of the parallelism in the algorithm, making it slower.

1.1. Make sure to use the minimum synchronization possible for your algorithm. With `openmp` for instance, a simple change from `synchronized` to `atomic` can result in a relevant difference.

1.2 Sometimes a worse sequential algorithm might offer better parallelism opportunities, if you have the chance to try something else it might be worth the shot.

2. **Memory bandwidth limitation**: it is very common that the most "trivial" implementation of an algorithm is not optimized for locality, which implies heavy communication costs between the processors and the main memory.

2.1 Optimize for locality: this means get to know where your application will run, what are the available cache memories and how to change your data structures to maximize cache usage.

3. **Too much parallelization overhead**: sometimes the parallel task is so "small" that the overhead for thread/process creation is too big compared to the parallel region total time, which causes a poor speedup or even speed-down.

Answer (score 0):

All of RSFalcon7's suggestions can be combined into a "super rule": do as much as possible in unshared resources (L1 & L2 caches) - implying economizing on code and data requirements - and if you need to go to shared resources do as much as possible in L3 before going to RAM before using synchronization (the CPU cycles required to synchronize is variable but is slower - or much slower - than accessing RAM) before going to disks.

If you plan to utilize hyperthreading I have found that code compiled with gcc will utilize hyperthreading better with optimization level O1 than with, say, O2 or O3.